# How can I install javadoc on JavaFX 15 Platform on NetBeans 12.1

Tags: javafx, netbeans, javadoc

I installed NetBeans12.1 with JDK 15 and JavaFX15, but I can't add Javadoc into the JavaFX platform. The NetBeans shows this message
[Error to add Javadoc platform for JavaFX15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esZNL.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is currently an open issue ([How to add javadoc in Netbeans #44](http://How%20to%20add%20javadoc%20in%20Netbeans%20#44)) that has yet to be resolved, but based on your environment, you may be able to find a workaround that fits your setup.

Here's what worked for me (Java with Ant):

- Download the JavaFX Documentation from the https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
- Add javafx.base, javafx.controls, javafx.fxml, javafx.graphics, javafx.media, javafx.swing, javafx.web folders (found in openjfx--javadoc/) in the Ant Library Manager under the Javadoc tab/ Add ZIP/Folder. I received a warning that the specified folder did not contain a plist file.
- Restart your NetBeans IDE.

Here are some additional resources that may help:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3296
- https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/44